# Get the last record in a belongsToMany association

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have a belongsToMany association between Appointment and Status models. The below query returns all of the statuses and I want to alter it to pull the last status assigned to the appointment.

```
$query = Appointment::query();
            $query->with('statuses');
            $query->with("agent");
            $query->with("instruction_type");
            $query->with("sign_up_customer");
            $table = Datatables::of($query);
```

I have tried altering the query with this but it doesn't work.

```
$query->with('statuses')->latest();
```

This is my raw query:

```
select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = '1' limit 1
select count(*) as aggregate from (select '1' as `row_count` from `appointments`) count_row_table

select * from `appointments` limit 100 offset 0

select `statuses`.*, `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` as `pivot_appointment_id`, `appointment_status`.`status_id` as `pivot_status_id` from `statuses` inner join `appointment_status` on `statuses`.`id` = `appointment_status`.`status_id` where `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` in ('2') order by `created_at` desc

select * from `agents` where `agents`.`id` in ('1')

select * from `instruction_types` where `instruction_types`.`id` in ('1')

select * from `organisations` where `organisations`.`id` in ('1')
```

So this works, but it runs two queries on Statuses

```
$query = Appointment::with(['statuses' => function ($query) {
                $query->latest()->first();
            }]);
            $query->with("agent");
            $query->with("instruction_type");
            $query->with("sign_up_customer");
            $table = Datatables::of($query);
```

Comment: Try this first just to see if your relationship it working correctly. $query->with('statuses')->latest()->get();   or Appointment::latest()->with('statuses') -- Also please show us any error messages you get making sure debug mode is enabled

Comment: I run the following in Tinker: $query = App\Appointment::query(); then $query->with('statuses')->latest()->get(); It shown the only Appointment and all of the Statuses associated with it rather than just the latest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the latest record from the database, you should have a `created_at` column to reach that. In this case, you can do something like that:

```
Appointment::with(['statuses' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
}])->get();
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it *always* returns the first Status assigned to Appointment.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$query->with(["statuses"=>function($q){
    $q->latest();
}])->get()
```

not tested but guess it should work

Comment: that didn't work. Examining the raw query, it appears to be identical to the one produced by the original.

Comment: @showFocus - I always thought latest() should work in general when chaining? I do a similar query and it works fine, Have you tried to inspect the query that is hitting the DB?

Comment: @Birdy I have added my query copied from debugbar

Comment: @Birdy I removed ->get() from the code you supplied as it was querying the DB twice for the same info. I've used latest before and it worked as expected. Not on this occasion, unfortunately!